# purrr: element-wise length comparison of multiple lists?

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I have three lists with 2 elements each. How do I check whether every element has the same length in every list? Preferably using purrr. Thank you!

```
list.a = list(a = 1, b = c(1, 2))
list.b = list(a = 2, b = c(1, 2))
list.c = list(a = 3, b = c(1, 2, 3))
```

Should return T, T, F.

Comment: Do you want to query for a specific length, i.e. `a = 1`, `b = 2`, or should this be based on some summary statistic? Something like `map_lgl(list(list.a, list.b, list.c), ~ all(map_dbl(.x, length) == c(1,2)))`, although there is likely a more concise syntax

Comment: I think `mapply(function(x, y, z) identical(length(x), length(y), length(z)),
         list.a, list.b, list.c)` does what I want. I want to filter out the elements that do not have the same length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure on the requirement but here's 2 potentially usefully snippets.

```
map_lgl(transpose(list(list.a, list.b, list.c)), ~ var(lengths(.x))==0)
```

---

```
  a     b 
 TRUE FALSE
```

or for a more general output you can manipulate easier

```
map_dfr(list(list.a, list.b, list.c), ~map(.x, length))
```

---

```
      a     b
1     1     2
2     1     2
3     1     3
```

Answer (score 1):

For any two lists:

```r
all(lengths(list.a)==lengths(list.b))
```

To check if all lists are equal:

```r
same_length <- function (x, y) all(lengths(x) == lengths(y))
Reduce(f, list(list.a, list.b, list.c))
```

If you want to use `purrr`:

```r
same_length <- function (x, y) all(lengths(x) == lengths(y))
purrr::reduce(list(list.a, list.b, list.c), f)
```

Answer (score 1):

*each element has the same length in every list?* - This would be a single `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Based on your expected output and task I think you want to compare for specific length of list elements.

```
master_list <- list(list.a, list.b, list.c)
map_lgl(master_list, ~ all(lengths(.x) == 1:2))
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: You are right I phrased it incorrectly. I want an element-wise length comparison, i.e. is element 1 of each list the same length and so on. I think this does what I want: `mapply(function(x, y, z) identical(length(x), length(y), length(z)), list.a, list.b, list.c)`